# Is there way to install zip on sagemakder lab?

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I need a way to download files off the Sagemaker lab notebook, anyone has good suggestions on how to do it? Currently only viable solution seems to be using zipfiles from Python since I can't do apt-get install on sagemaker lab

Answer (score 1):

`apt-get` isn't supported on Studio Lab yet.

If you wanted to download multiple files at once, you can tar them instead of zipping, like -
`tar -czvf studio-files.tar.gz *` from the terminal, and download the tar file as mentioned through the UI.

Answer (score 0):

In the terminal you can install it with `conda install zip -c conda-forge -y`

Answer (score -1):

We can download the file by context menu on Studio Lab. Or if you have GitHub account, you can download files through the GitHub repository.

[image]